# Рандомный выбор интернет адресов из списка

Tags: javascript

Ребят, возможно ли на JS реализовать такую идею: при нажатии на кнопку совершается переход на рандомный адрес (сайт) из списка, лежащего в корне сайта? В гугле не забанили, но не понимаю, как правильно сформулировать запрос в эту сторону, не программер и руки слегка не оттуда ). Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: `из списка, лежащего в корне сайта` В каком виде данный список?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно так

```js
// Ссылки на сайты в виде массива, или можно их в отдельном файле, и потом просто подключить к странице
let arr = [
          'https://www.youtube.com', 
          'https://yandex.ru', 
          'https://www.google.com', 
          'https://ru.stackoverflow.com'
          ]

let link = document.getElementById('click')

//функция рандомного элемента
function clickRandom(arr) {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
    return arr[rand]
}

//функция клика на кнопку
link.addEventListener('click', function(){
location.replace(clickRandom(arr))
})
```

```html
<button id="click">Click</button>
```